# Why doesn't &(NULL->local) cause my program to crash?

Tags: c, pointers

This is a example code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct substruct {
    int integer1;
    unsigned char boolean1;
    unsigned char boolean2;

    char *ptr1;
    char *ptr2;
} substruct_t;

typedef struct tester {
    char *ptr1; //0x00
    char *ptr2; //0x08


    unsigned char boolean1; //0x10
    unsigned char boolean2; //0x11
    int integer1; //0x12

    // padding bypte 0x16 -> 0x18
    char *ptr3; //0x18
    // It is not pointer.
    substruct_t local; // 0x20

    char *ptr4;
} tester_t;


int main()
{
    tester_t *tester;
    tester = NULL;
    printf("0\n");
    substruct_t *localptr = &(tester->local);
    printf("1\n");
    // seg fault
    substruct_t test_local = tester->local;
    printf("2\n");
    substruct_t *test_local_ptr = &test_local;
    printf("3\n");

    // localptr = &(0x20); ???
    // void *voidptr = 0x20;
    // substruct_t *testptr = (substruct_t *)&(voidptr);
    // printf("4\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't the program die at `&(tester->local)` line?
I want to know why `test->local` causes a crash, but `&(test->local)` doesn't.

This is the output result.

```
$ gcc -Wall -g -o asdf asdf.c
$ ./asdf
0
1
[1]    1777 segmentation fault  ./asdf
```

0, 1 print but 2 not print. seg fault at `tester->local` line.

Comment: As the offending lines of code don't _do_ anything, it's not inconceivable that a compiler could optimize them away, eliminating the undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both lines dereference a NULL pointer, and doing so triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code.

With undefined behavior, there is no guarantee what your code will do.  It might crash, it might print strange results, or it might (as in your case with the first line) appear to work properly.  Additionally, making a seemingly unrelated code change, such as adding an unused local variable or a call to `printf` for debugging, can change how undefined behavior manifests.

Just because your code *could* crash doesn't mean it *will*.

That being said, what's *probably* happening is that the compiler looks at `&(tester->local)` and simply calculates the offset of the `local` member and adds that to the current value of `tester` without actually performing a dereference.  But again, this is undefined behavior and there's no guarantee of this.

Comment: Actually `&(tester->local)` is not and cannot be a pointer dereference. The code just took a dependency on not tagged memory model.

Comment: @Joshua "Actually &(tester->local) is not and cannot be a pointer dereference. " --> Sounds like you are suggesting a limitation on the UB of `&(tester->local)`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: It's more like the compiler can't emit instructions the processor doesn't have. There's no instruction for "give me the address of the last load" (and even if there were, it wouldn't work because of multi-core or interrupts).

Comment: Also, while I'm not confident it's sane through a variable, I will pound on the compiler authors who make this undefined behavior: `(ptrdiff_t)&(((struct tester *)NULL)->local)`. Because that at least is well defined. (No it's not quite a constant yet because NULL need not be binary 0 but it has a definite value that can be output and will be the same on every compilation.)